# How to check the logs of Mac OS X when running a python exe compiler software?

Tags: python-3.x, macos, logging

**Environment**

Python 3.7

Mac OS Catalina 10.15

**Problem**

I am developing a software with Python for Mac OS X. I will compile it with Nuitka.
When I run my compiled program, it doesn't work.

When I was searching for solutions on Google, some people speak about checking the log system of the Mac OS.

So I found it here: Finder > Applications > Utilities > Console

The console is full of logs system messages. My problem is I don't know how can I filter all these logs to show only the ones connected to the execution of my software.

I use the logging module to create a log file for my python script but this log file is not produced. I guess program bug before it can create a log file.

Is there another way to check the logs?

**Edit:**

To compile my code, I execute this Nuitka command:

```
sudo python3 -m nuitka --standalone --plugin-enable=gevent --plugin-enable=qt-plugins --plugin-enable=pylint-warnings --show-progress --show-scons --follow-imports --recurse-all --windows-icon=phonebot_icon.icns MyApp.py
```

The result is 2 folders:
MyApp.build
MyApp.dist

MyApp.dist contains the executable file "MyApp" and some .so files.

From Finder, I can't browse MyApp.dist as it is seen as unknown file. So the only way to run the executable file is from terminal. I do:

```
sudo open MyApp
```

A new terminal window open and I get this output:

```
Last login: Thu Sep  3 12:46:32 on ttys001
/Users/gauthierbtz/Dropbox/cff/Python/MyApp/MyApp.dist/MyApp ; exit;
(base) gauthierbtz@MacBook-de-Gauthier ~ % /Users/gauthierbtz/Dropbox/cff/Python/MyApp/MyApp.dist/MyApp ; exit;
Password:
LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed for the application /Applications/MyApp.app with error -10810.
```

It looks like it try to go to Applications folder to open the MyApp.app which doesn't exist.

Comment: I have my python folder in my documents where is located my source files. Then I compile it here with Nuitka which produces a MyApp.dist folder which contains an exe MyApp file. I run the exe by typing in terminal :"open MyApp". I even did a "sudo open MyApp"

Comment: Thanks for helping. That is what I did. I never said it was a .exe file. I meant the binary executable. I open it from terminal in order to get some error messages but I see only this "LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed with error -10810 for the file /Users/gb/myapp/dist/MyApplication.app." It is not useful at all. I need to investigate in logs.

Comment: It seems pretty useful. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/181026/lsopenurlswithrole-failed-with-error-10810-cant-open-install-os-x-yosemite#181031 you can even google that error and find similar issues.

Comment: Yes, I did and it works. My program doesn't work because it is much more complex. That is why I need some tools to investigate. But Mac OS X is very poor of tools to debug. I don't see how to investigate deeper in the issue. Is it permission issue? Is it relative or full path issue? Is it missing some modules, library or files? Is it problem of signature code? So I need the Mac OS tools to investigate my issue as Mac OS just show LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed with error -10810 which I repeat, it is not useful at all as it doesn't explain you clearly where is the source of problem.

Comment: I added more details in edit.

Comment: for info, I already tried the "chmod +x" solution your proposed as a link and it didn't change anything.

Comment: Looks much better. You are creating a .dist, is that a [distribution definition](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/DistributionDefinitionRef/Chapters/Introduction.html) ? It sounds like you might need to "install" your app so it gets converted to a MyApp.app.

Comment: Thanks. The problem is I don't know how to make an installable package from this Nuitka dist folder. So I tried with Pyinstaller which make a MyApp.app folder with everything, but I get same error message -10810. That is why I asked here how to get some log system from Mac OS in order to investigate deeper in the source of issue.

Comment: I tried using your build command with the hello.py and it created a hello.dist, which contained a hello binary file that I could execute.  I'm running osx 10.14.xx so maybe the issue is in catelina? Did you try putting your program in the folder that the error message is declaring? Maybe something is hardcoded to point there? Also, if somebody doesn't answer here, maybe file an issue on Nuitka's github too?

Comment: Thank you so much for trying to help. I copy paste the files and folders of MyApp.app in Applications/MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS/ and I get a new error message: Unable to block on application (GetProcessPID() returned 18446744073709551016)

Comment: I compiled the same with PyInstaller and same error "Unable to block on application (GetProcessPID() returned 18446744073709551016)"

Comment: That's impressive. I think what you'll need to do to resolve this is to start narrowing down the deps. 1st create a hello world -> build to hello.dist and make sure it runs. Don't use sudo in there at all. If that works, then make a qt hello world, and see if that works. You seem to have included most information, but it would be really handy if somebody else could reproduce it.

Comment: Thank you so much Matt. I work on it.

Comment: An app is a package directory on macos: right-click the app and select View Package Contents to browse.  System logging may be filtered and viewed in the /Applications/Utilities/Console.app program.

Comment: I'm a little confused by something you say. You have an executable file called MyApp and you call `sudo open MyApp` shouldn't you just call `./MyApp`?